# Font and color settings for Code Review in Visual Studio 2015; some unreadable text

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The "removed" text on the left side of the "Code Review" window is showing as black text on a black background.

It seems that entire removed lines have no border, but removed words have a red border.

I can't read black text on a black background, with or without a red border.

Where can I update the Font and Colors settings for Code Review in Visual Studio 2015?

Yes, I do set colors elsewhere in Visual Studio, but I have not selected black on black anywhere, nor have I selected a thick red border anywhere.

Any help appreciated; this is making Code Review unusable for me.

P.S. When I select the text, some of the background changes from black to very dark blue or purple and I can then barely read the text.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the color selections in the "Text Editor" section under "diff".

The names of the items don't correlate well to the observed results, but the colors for "code review" can be edited:

- Diff - Removed (Original) - foreground: 1) (differnt) word outline, 2) toolbar highlight
- Diff - removed (Original) - background: 1) text background
- Diff - Differences (Latest): text background of **unchanged** text on right
- Diff - Differences (Original): text background of **unchanged** text on left

I believe that the Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor may begin with "high contrast" as its base theme, leaving some colors too dark sometimes, thus my original experience of black-on-black.